# Eliminate some class attributes from Spring @Valid when editing

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

I have a problem with my simple CRUD application in Spring MVC. My domain User class have a attribute named `login`.

```
@Size(min = 6, max = 30, message = "{addUser.validation.login}")
@UserLogin
private String login;
```

I also have validator that check if registered login is exist in database:

```
@Component
public class UserLoginValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UserLogin, String> {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public void initialize(UserLogin a) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String t, ConstraintValidatorContext cvc) {

        User user;
        try {
            user = (User) userService.getUserByLogin(t);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return true;
        }

        if (user != null) {
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    } 
}
```

In my controller class among others I have methods:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAddNewCustomerForm(@ModelAttribute("addUser") User addUser) {
       return "addUser";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processAddNewCustomerForm(Model model, @ModelAttribute("addUser") @Valid User user, BindingResult result) {

       if (result.hasErrors()) {
          return "addUser";
       }

        if (user.getUserID() == 0) {
           user.setCreateDate(new Date());
           userService.addUser(user);
        } else {
           user.setCreateDate(new Date());
           userService.editUser(user);
        }

           return "redirect:/users";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "{id}/edit")
public String editUser(Model model, @PathVariable int id) {

       User user = new User();

       user = this.userService.getUserById(id);
       user.setPassword2(user.getPassword());
       model.addAttribute("addUser", user);
       model.addAttribute("users", userService.getAllUsers());
       return "addUser";
}

@InitBinder
public void initialiseBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
       binder.setValidator(userValidator);
}
```

Now my question is how to disable login attribute validation - only when editing?
Is the simple way to do this, except separate methods and views to coresponding for editing and adding method?

Comment: What is the `userValidator` you are setting? Judging from the annotation you are simply using java bean validation, so why register a custom validator? If you are using ava bean validation you can use validation groups to specify which rules to execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create 2 different Controller classes and add

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder, WebRequest request) {
    binder.setAllowedFields("login", "someAnotherField"...);
}
```

Including or excluding the login from validation.

If you need just one class you can try to use POST/PUT for create and edit

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder, HttpServletRequest request) {
    String httpMethod = request.getMethod();
    if ("POST".equals(httpMethod)) {
        // registration
        binder.setAllowedFields("name", "email", "password");
    } else if ("PUT".equals(httpMethod)) {
        // update
        binder.setAllowedFields("email", "password");
    }

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String create(@Valid User user, BindingResult result,
        ModelMap modelMap) {
    //registration...
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public String create(@Valid User user, BindingResult result,
        ModelMap modelMap) {
    //update...
}
```

As described [here](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/81059-exclude-form-bindings-on-fields-depending-on-the-called-controller-method)